# Parsing a hierarchical config file structure with Python

Tags: python, configuration, hierarchical, configparser

I'm using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples) for a project with a configuration file that is getting to large. I plan to split it but maintain a central config file that points to the others.

I haven't seen this in the documentation, but can ConfigParser handle a hierarchical configuration file structure? Can I somehow point it from one config file to another automatically?

Of course I could do it manually or better yet, create a module that handles this using ConfigParser as a low-level tool, but I'm sure I'm not the first to tackle thisproblem - do you know of a different package that handles this? or perhaps a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Python module as configuration file, say config.py so you just have to import it :

```
import config
```

Comment: I've posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067651/configparser-vs-import-config)

Comment: This is only a good idea *if you can completely trust your users*.  Otherwise, what's to stop them from calling arbitrary functions from within the config.py file?  Functions such as `unlink`.

Answer (score 1):

XML has XInclude support.  If you use `lxml` when parsing an XML file, it will go off and find the configuration files that you've included through [`<xinclude>` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx)

Comment: That's exactly the functionality I'm looking for, however I find `XML` to be tedious. Maybe `json` would be a better fit.

Comment: I agree XML is tedious.  Fortunately, lxml supports various features that make it *less* so.  The two main ones are `xpath` and `ElementMaker`.  xpath let's you use search strings, pretty much like directory names, to find elements in the XML tree.  That makes reading in a file *much* simpler.  `ElementMaker` simplifies the creation of XML.  Create `E`, an instance of `ElementMaker`, and you can create new XML elements simply. For example, create `<val>100</val>` as `node = E.val(100)`. or `<my_node>yup</my_node>` as `E.my_node('yup')`.

Comment: `lxml` is great and I use it every time I parse `XML` files, however my users will be updating the config frequently using a text editor, and I was thinking of them...

Comment: Yeah, xml, whilst "readable", isn't really all that readable.