# ConfigParser vs. import config

Tags: python, configuration, configparser, import-module

[ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) is the [much debated](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout) vanilla configuration parser for Python.
However you can simply `import config` where `config.py` has python code which sets configuration parameters.

What are the pros\cons of these two approaches of configuration?
When should I choose each?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The biggest issue I see with `import config` is that you don't know *what* will happen when you import it.  Yes, you will get a set of symbols that are naturally referenced using a `.` style interface.  But the code in the configuration file can also do who-knows-what.  Now, if you completely trust your users, then allowing them to do whatever they feel like in the config file is possibly a good thing.  However, if you have unknown quantities, or you want to protect users from themselves, then having a configuration file in a more traditional format will be safer and more secure.

Comment: That's a REALLY good point that I had not considered because of that whole trust in myself.

Answer (score 8):

This completley depends on your needs and goals for the script.  One way really isnt "better", just different.  For a very detailed discussion on most of pythons config parsers (including `ConfigParser` and `config` modules), see:

[Python Wiki - ConfigParserShootout](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout)

Answer (score 6):

"import config" is very simple, flexible and powerfull but, since it can do anything, it might be dangerous if the config.py is not in a safe place.

Answer (score 4):

IMO it comes down to a matter of personal style. Do you intend for 3rd parties to edit your config? If so, maybe it makes sense to have a more "natural" configuration style a la `ConfigParser` that is not as technical and that may not be too far over the heads of your target audience.

Many popular projects such as [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) and [Django](http://djangoproject.com) use the "native" configuration style which is essentially just a Python module. Fabry has `fabfile.py` and Django has `settings.py`.

Overall, you're going to have a lot more flexibility using a native approach of importing a module simply because you can do anything you want in that file, including defining functions, classes, etc. because it's just another Python module you're importing.