# Passing configs from `.txt` file into argparse? (Similar to youtube-dl's `--config-location`)

Tags: python, argparse, youtube-dl

I have a program with ~20 configs, which I would like to be accessed from the command-line via `argparse`, either by something like `--config_1 'This is the first config'` or `--config-location <path_to_config_file>`, where the path to the config file would be a `.txt` of form:

```
--config_1 'This is the first config'
--config_2 '2nd Config'
--config_3 3
...
```

Currently, my code looks something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--config_1')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

This approach was inspired by `youtube-dl`'s `--config-location`. If there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, suggestions are also appreciated and welcome. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` supports something similar out of the box.

```
parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.parse_args()
```

Now any argument starting with `@` will be treated as a filename to be read, which each line being treated as a separate argument. This would require your file to look like

```
--config_1
This is the first config
--config_2
2nd Config
--config_3
3
...
```

instead.

[What `youtube-dl` does](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/options.py#L42) is simply open the file, read its contents, and split it on whitespace similar to how the shell would.

Comment: Thank you for your (quick) reply! Is it possible to allow `--config-location` as well as `--config_1`, but if `--config-location` is specified, ignore `--config_1`? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "any argument starting with @ will be treated as a filename to be read" - how are arguments treated as filenames?

Comment: With the parser shown, `yourscript @foo.txt` would be equivalent to `yourscript --config_1 'This is the first config' --config_2 '2nd config' --config_3 3`.

Comment: The machinery for processing such a file isn't really exposed by `ArgumentParser`, so if you want `--config-location foo.txt` to be the same as `@foo.txt`, you'd have to implement your own processing of `foo.txt` after parsing the arguments.

Comment: I managed to get it to work - thank you! A follow up question if I may, how would I pass a dictionary as an argument from `foo.txt`? I'm able to get it to work for strings, ints, etc. but not dictionaries.

Comment: Since everything you pass is a string which needs to be parsed, you'd have to do something like pass a JSON object and use `type=json.loads` when you define the option.

Answer (score 0):

**With that many command line options, a better approach would be to make a configuration file.** There are two ways of doing this:

The first is to create a separate Python file. Create a file called `config.py`:

```py
config_1 = 'This is the first config'
config_2 = '2nd config'
config_3 = 3
```

Then, in another file (say, `prog.py`):

```py
import config

print(config.config_1)
print(config.config_2)
print(config.config_3)
```

This will output:

```py
This is the first config
2nd config
3
```

---

The second way is an improvement upon the above approach. You can use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). For example, with an example `config.ini`:

```
[DEFAULT]
config_1 = 'This is the first config'
config_2 = '2nd config'
config_3 = 3
```

and an example `prog.py`:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
print(config['DEFAULT']['config_1'])
print(config['DEFAULT']['config_2'])
print(config['DEFAULT']['config_3'])
```

We can get:

```py
This is the first config
2nd config
3
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8067651/17769815) for a discussion between these two approaches.