# Read dictionary from `.txt` file into argparse

Tags: python, configuration, config, argparse

I would like to read in a dictionary from a config `.txt` file into `argparse`

Current `main.py` code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('--config_1', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--config_2')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

I can run my script like: `python main.py @config.txt`

Where `config.txt` contains `--config_1`

Specifically, I would like to read in `config_2` from `config.txt` as a dictionary - something like:

```
--config_1
--config_2 {
    'key1': [], 
    'key2': ['value1', 'value2']
}
```

This is a follow-up question to: [Passing configs from `.txt` file into argparse? (Similar to youtube-dl's `--config-location`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620978/passing-configs-from-txt-file-into-argparse-similar-to-youtube-dls-conf)

---

Edit: For clarification, I'm getting an error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments:  --config_2 { 'key1': [], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2'] }
```

Comment: "This is a follow-up question to" I don't understand how it is a different question.

Comment: Here I'm specifically asking how to pass dictionaries, where as the previous question was just a general question on how to use text files to write configs in.

Comment: What actually is the difficulty? If you try your existing code, how does the result differ from your expectation? For example, does it correctly handle the `config_2` value being split across multiple lines? (If not, *what is the rule* that you want the code to use, in order to decide how many lines are in the value?) Does it create a dictionary? (Is the question really just "how do I create a dictionary from a string that represents it"?) Is something else wrong?

Comment: As asked, the answer is "you need to write code that interprets the contents of the file properly", but that is too broad for a Stack Overflow question. Start by making sure you *understand* how the answer to the previous question works.

Comment: I think the answer is that argparse doesn't have anything to do this automatically. It treats the file as if the contents were command-line arguments, it won't parse it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The default reader, as documented should accept

```
--config_1
--config_2
value
```

The alternate that's also documented would accept

```
--config_1
--config_2 value
```

Both of these are equivalent to the user typing

```
python main.py --config_1 --config_2 value
```

This prefix mechanism does not add to the parsing power of `argparse`, it just provides a way of entering a large number of arguments as an editable file.

```
 --config_1
 --config_2 
 "{'key1': [], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}"
```

may work, resulting a `args.config_2` string value as quoted.  Parsing that as a `dict` is  up to you.

Loading your file as `json` might be better.

The key point is that the `@` file is read right at the start of parsing, and strings inserted into the `sys.argv` list, just as though the user had typed them.  This is done before any real parsing is done.  The custom file reader, if any, should return a list of strings.

Other posters have asked about entering generic key:value pairs.  `argparse` does not handle this directly.  The answers to such questions nearly always involve a user provided parser/splitter, either as a custom `type`, action class, or post parsing action.  You don't get extra points for doing "everything" in `argparse.